# Changing iFrame Content to PHP Content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I'm wondering how I can get my iFrames content (html) to update to code from a textarea and add php tags around it to make it actually appear.

Code:

```
$("#iframehtml").contents().find("html").html(editor.doc.getValue());
```

And lets say for instance editor.doc.getValue() is equal to:

```
$var = "Test";
print $var;
```

It should print "Test" to the screen.

Comment: Javascript cannot run PHP. You could theorectically make an AJAX call to the server, where the input PHP is run and the output captured for return, but you are then talking about a potentially serious security issue in allowing arbitrary code to be executed on your server.

Comment: No, I mean to use Javascript to update the contents of an iFrame with php code that can be executed.

Comment: it's the `that can be executed.` part that isn't clear. If you literally want it executed, that's not possible as explained by Mike.

Comment: Same thing. Either the javascript updates teh iframe DOM based on running PHP code (which it cannot do), or the PHP code is sent to a server to be executed - a serious security vulnerability - with the output updated into the iframe. If you are trying to build a PHP fiddle type of site, then perhaps your best bet is to leverage the capabilities of such a site.

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean now, and yes you're right, but is there any type of way to do this? And yes the website is sorta like a php fiddle type of website but different. Same idea, so is this possible at all? How would it be done?

Comment: Yes, like I said it is possible, obviously it is if PHP Fiddle does it.  My suggestion would be for you to use their API's or similar to do this rather than build it yourself. I don't mean offense, but if you are not even at the point to understand how something like this might be done, you are probably a long way away from knowing how this could be done securely.

Comment: I do know how this could be done, and I've tried many different ways but none have worked perfectly. I tried just updating the contents of a .php file with their input which does work, and the reason it works is because it temporarily edits it, not fully. Just edits the content of the iframe. I don't believe you're the one who understands how to do it.